# Not getting correct output when using async await inside forEach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async-await

In this code, I am getting a value 34 in the newArr. Which is expected and correct.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 34, 5, 6, 67, 4]
var val = 34

var newArr = []

arr.forEach((elm) => {

  if (val == elm)
    newArr.push(elm)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

But when I am using `async await` I am not getting any value in newArr.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 34, 5, 6, 67, 4]
var val = 34

var newArr = []

arr.forEach(async(elm) => {
  await setTimeout(function() {}, 10);
  if (val == elm)
    newArr.push(elm)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

I am new to Javascript and not able to understand why this is not working as I am expecting.

Comment: setTimeout does not return a promise

Comment: @mplungjan That's right but unrelated and therefore probably more confusing than helpful. `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10));` doesn't change the output and the visible behavior.

Comment: I assume this is an X/Y problem but we will not know if OP does not give  better usecase.

Comment: I was going to answer you, but the question was flagged as duplicated. 
this is normal behavior since the logic of javascript is to execute line by line. and since you have async execution, this will lead us to print the newArr before finishing the async code.  you can wrapp the arr.forEach with Promise.resolve and print it using await or then promise

Comment: var arr = [1, 2, 34, 5, 6, 67, 4]
var val = 34

var newArr = []

arr.map(async(elm) => {
 if (val == elm)
  await newArr.push(elm)
})

console.log(newArr)

Comment: I don't see any use of setTime out function